# Apache Spark and Kafka "exactly once" semantics

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have a Dataframe that I want to output to Kafka. This can be done manually doing a forEach using a Kafka producer or I can use a Kafka sink (if I start using Spark structured streaming).
I'd like to achieve an exactly once semantic in this whole process, so I want to be sure that I'll never have the same message committed twice.

1. If I use a Kafka producer I can enable the idempotency through Kafka properties, for what I've seen this is implemented using sequence numbers and producersId, but I believe  that in case of stage/task failures the Spark retry mechanism might create duplicates on Kafka, for example if a worker node fails, the entire stage will be retried and will be an entire new producer pushing messages causing duplicates?
2. Seeing the fault tolerance table for kafka sink [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#fault-tolerance-semantics) I can see that:
   [image]
   Kafka Sink supports at-least-once semantic, so the same output can be sinked more than once.

Is it possible to achieve exactly once semantic with Spark + Kafka producers or Kafka sink?
If is possible, how?

Answer (score -1):

Kafka doesn't support exactly-once semantic. They have a guarantee only for at-least-once semantic. They just propose how to avoid duplicate messages. If your data has a unique key and is stored in a database or filesystem etc., you can avoid duplicate messages.

For example, you sink your data into HBase, each message has a unique key as an HBase row key. when it gets the message that has the same key, the message will be overwritten.

I hope this article will be helpful:
https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-to-amazon-s3-exactly-once/

Comment: Kafka producer supports exactly once semantic: https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/. The case that you've described is different, is the case of a kafka consumer (kafka connect) saving data in another source.

Comment: @LFilips  A bit too quick off the mark, he describes both. Producer can also fail with exactly once after restart.

Comment: An upsert to a DB is idempotency which helps here.

Comment: Having an idempotent consumer of my data is a viable option, but I wanted to understand if is possible to guarantee this on producer side. According to the Kafka documentation that i've linked is possible (or at least the broker will not write twice message from the same producer if idempotency is enabled using producerIDs and sequence numbers). 
What i wanted to understand is how the kafka producer api will behave together with the Spark retrying mechanism. @thebluephantom can you explain more this "Producer can also fail with exactly once after restart"?

Comment: Kafka **does** support exactly once processing. Spark snapshots even further the guarantees

Comment: @LFilips If the transaction batch or its ID is not preserved in the (small) window between restarts, then there is potential for dropped messages by the producer. Regardles of idempotent or not settings

Comment: spark restart will lose producers pid and seqID, therefore can cause dups. if you can make sure your spark don't ever restart, then it can achieve idempotent produce. but no one can make that assumption.